# PostgreSQL and the mystery of timestamps

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I think one of the two scourges of IT are timestamps and time zones (the other being character encoding) where one keeps stumbling upon again and again...

In that regard I currently have a problem related to different timestamps within a Java application storing into a PostgreSQL database.

For keeping things simple, assume having the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ts_test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  utc timestamp without time zone,
  local timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

So, I have to store a UTC time stamp and a local one, which in my case is central Europe summer time, so currently UTC+2.

Further assume having 2 entries in the table, which output on the psql console as follows (the database runs in UTC):

```
# select id,  utc, local, local-utc as diff from ts_test;
 id |         utc         |         local          |   diff   
----+---------------------+------------------------+----------
  1 | 2012-06-27 12:00:00 | 2012-06-27 12:00:00+00 | 00:00:00
  2 | 2012-06-27 12:00:00 | 2012-06-27 14:00:00+00 | 02:00:00
(2 rows)
```

Now, several questions arise:

- What exactly does the output in the local column mean?
- How does the system know the timezone, I inserted the value in?
- How can I see the real raw value (e.g. milliseconds) stored?

I would have assumed, that the first line's local "12:00:00+00" means, that it's 12:00 in UTC, which again is 14:00 in CEST. But it seems (and so I was told by our database admin), that the 2nd line's local "14:00:00+00" is the correct value for 14:00 CEST - which is supported by the diff of 2 hours.

But to produce the 2nd line via sql insert, I have to write

```
insert into ts_test (id, utc, local) values (2, '2012-06-27 12:00:00', '2012-06-27 16:00:00+02');
```

which again does not support the predication.

So, to sum up this long question - can anyone enlighten me on how this whole thing works in detail, what the output is supposed to mean and how one should write local time stamps correctly into the database?

Comment: The `+00` part is the frozen time-zone offset. You probably want to capture the actual time-zone name. Any region that observes DST will flip from one "time zone" to another throughout the year. In any case, your local time is stored as zero-offset, meaning UTC, which is incorrect. More information in the [Postgres date/time documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: @tadman: Thanks for the hint. I already considered the PostgresQL documentation, but couldn't answer my problem with it yet. - According to the page you linked to, it says that timestamps are always stored in UTC, but output in the specific time zone. So, is one part of the problem, that my database runs in UTC, allthough I write local dates in CEST? When I change the timezone parameter to 'Europe/Berlin', then i get an output of +2 for all locals and diffs. That again would support my assumption above for 1st line, yet I was told, that 2nd line is correct. *still puzzled*

Comment: The column type is actually "timestamp with time zone *offset*", as the actual time-zone that yielded that offset is not recorded. There are many time-zones that are UTC+2 at various times of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output of the `local` column, the time zone of your SQL session is set to `UTC` or `GMT` and not the time zone where you live in. Presumably this is what you mean by: *the database runs in UTC*. This is the root of the problem, but let's try to elaborate.

The db itself, as a data repository, doesn't have a timezone, but each SQL session has its own timezone.

When they're requested by a SQL session, the values of `timestamp without time zone` are **not** rotated to the session's time zone and **not** presented with a time offset, whereas the values for `timestamp with time zone` are rotated to the session's timezone and presented with the time offset for this time zone. That's the difference between both.

The time zone is never stored in any of the datatypes, because when reading the value, all that matters is the time zone of the SQL session that is requesting this value.

Setting your SQL time zone to `UTC` is not a good idea because it contradicts this other part of your question:

> So, I have to store a UTC time stamp and a local one, which in my case
>   is central Europe summer time, so currently UTC+2

Let the SQL session know your real time zone, and it will start to work as intended. If you don't, `timestamp with time zone` is essentially useless.

Also note that storing the same time in `utc timestamp without time zone` and `local timestamp with time zone` doesn't make sense, because you could always get the `utc` with:

```
SELECT local AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM ts_test WHERE...
```

**EDIT**: answers to questions in the comments:

> Q: you are saying that if my timezone is set to my local time in the
>   session, then I should see for example ...14:00:00+02 in local for a
>   utc value of ...12:00:00

Yes.

> Q: And when writing something into the local field from my application,
>   it matters which timezone is set there?

Exactly.

> Q: How does one set this in JDBS-session?

I don't know JDBC but at the SQL level, that would be for example:

```
 SET timezone='Europe/Berlin';
```

Normally it's automatically set from the environment but it can be forced at various levels including `postgresql.conf`. Setting it explicitly in the session will override anything else.

> Q: can I see the raw value of the timestamp somehow, to make sure it's
>   not just a representation problem when displaying

I'm not aware of how to do that except with [pageinspect](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) which operates at the lower level.

Comment: I was sure someone would say, that it does not make sense to store both utc and local, but allthough I fully agree, I have this situation in my project and have to deal with it. (And there is a reason for that which is out of scope here.) Concerning your remark with the session's timezone, you are saying that if my timezone is set to my local time in the session, then I should see for example ...14:00:00+02 in local for a utc value of ...12:00:00? And when writing something into the local field from my application, it matters which timezone is set there? How does one set this in JDBS-session?

Comment: And, can I see the raw value of the timestamp somehow, to make sure it's not just a representation problem when displaying?